# Using GroupedItemsPage as main Menu

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm kind of standing on a pipe (if that saying works as it does in german) with my current problem.

I would like to create a Windows Store app which uses the GroupedItemsPage as kind of a main Menu with each tile navigating to a new page/part of the application.

Now all Tutorials/Examples I found are using the GroupItemsPage to display the same kind of content. So each tile is of the same kind of datatype and mostly stored in a list or something.

The step between coming from a background where I would love to simply create each tile by doing something like `SettingsPage mySettingsPage = new SettingsPage();` and adding that to the right View to something different is difficult right now.

The only idea I would have right now to fill my GroupedItemsPage would be to create a new DataSource of a generic Type and add each and every single page to this DataSource, but that seems strange to me ...

What's the best practice here?

Comment: Firstly, I would check into the 8.1 Hub sample, as it seems like it's right up your alley. The GroupedItemsPage is really designed to display data, so if you want your data to be links, you'll have to do as you suggested and add some kind of identifier to the pages you want to the DataSource. This could be just a string identifier which your click events use to decide how to navigate (or open a flyout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=3a5ca8204ec61147&id=3A5CA8204EC61147%2135841&authkey=!AAOLlNWZh4K-FkQ

to main page add this in xaml:

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = e.Parameter;
}
```

and copy from this project classes to your project.